# Azure Response Time Monitoring per Url with a range

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, azure-dashboard

I am trying to configure the dashboard consists few business critical functionality which we needs to focus for performance monitoring based on the SLAs.

Example a landing page url retrieves a records needs to be faster and accepted SLA is

Green < 1sec 
Amber 1 sec - 2 secs
Red > 2 secs

We were able to configure the same in SPLUNK based on flat file logs. However we could not able to configure similar thing in Azure.

[image]

As of now I could not able to create a dashboard for our requirement. Any type of graphical representation is Ok for us. Based on this monitoring we might need to react and improve the performance over the period of time when it goes slow.

Comment: Not sure if I misunderstood you: suppose in a time range(like 1 day), if the average response time of the url_1 is less than 1s, then in the graph shows it's fine etc. Is it correct?

Comment: @IvanYang, yes. For a single request url average time for last 24 hours goes more than 2 it is not good as per SLA. So we need to monitor on daily basis to act on it, if its continuously more than 2 secs. I am not sure it can be done using Log Analytics with Kusto scripting . Syntax looks difficult

Comment: You can try using Serverless360 API monitoring and I guess it provides the requirement you are looking for.

Comment: why are you using average time and not 75th or 95th or 99th percentiles ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the below Kusto query in application insights:

```
requests 
| where timestamp > ago(2h) //set the time range
| where url == "http://localhost:54917/" //set the url here
| summarize avg_time =avg(duration)
| extend my_result = case(
avg_time<=1000,"good", //1000 milliseconds
avg_time<=2000,"normal",//2000 milliseconds
"bad"
)
```

Note:

1.the unit of avg_time is milliseconds

2.when avg_time <=1000 milliseconds, then in dashboard, it shows "good"; when <=2000 milliseconds, it shows "normal"; when >2000 milliseconds, it shows "bad".

The query result(change it to Chart):

[image]

Then in dashboard:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to change the chart type and somehow show where it is sitting in the SLA levels? We do this in SPLUNK and now we are looking some what similar in Log Analytics. We have around 15 url/dashboard to monitor,

Comment: @Developer, you mean something looks like the picture in your post? I'll take a try, but not sure if can figure it out.

Comment: Yes. It need not to be same picture, but somehow it needs to be visualized where it fits in a given Range of times :) Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: @Developer, hello, after some researching, I didn't find there're any doc / functions / solutions. Sorry for that:(.

Answer (score 4):

An approximated solution which can serve your purpose

use request time vs time char along with reference lines which can be your SLA thresholds
So you can figure out at this moment the response time is below or above the threshold

> `// Response time trend
>   // Chart request duration over the last 12 hours
>   requests
>   | where timestamp > ago(12h) 
>   | summarize avgRequestDuration=avg(duration) by bin(timestamp, 10m) // use a time grain of 10 minutes
>   | render timechart
>   | extend Green = 200
>   | extend Amber = 400
>   | extend red = 800`

it would look something like below

[image]

I think it is much more useful than your previous UI, which has kind of a meter like feel that gives you health indication at that moment, but with continuous time plot you get better picture of the trend

Answer (score 0):

If you run the same query in [Azure Workbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-grid-visualizations), you could use the "[thresholds](https://github.com/microsoft/Application-Insights-Workbooks/blob/master/Documentation/Visualizations/Grid.md#column-renderers)" renderer in grids or tiles to format cells with if/then/else like that for color for each range.

[image: thresholds]

would get you:
[image: thresholds in a grid]

you can then pin that grid/tiles/graph to an azure dashboard.  (if the query uses a workbooks time range parameter, it will inherit the [dashboard's time range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-overview#dashboard-time-ranges) and auto update as well.